# Multiple results on a Xml stack with lml (Python)

Tags: python, xml

This is what i want into an external xml file, through a for bucle add a registry with the same tag in `<Data>`as `<Availability>` and `<Price>` like this:

```
<UpdateInventoryRequest>
  <StartDate>21/12/2015</StartDate>
  <RoomId>1</RoomId>
  <Data>
    <Availability>1</Availability>
    <Price>100</Price>
    <Availability>3</Availability>
    <Price>120</Price>
  </Data>
</UpdateInventoryRequest>
```

And this is my code now, everytime returns the same value in all fields:

```
from lxml import etree
# Create Xml
root = etree.Element("UpdateInventoryRequest")
doc = etree.ElementTree(root)

root.append(etree.Element("StartDate"))
root.append(etree.Element("RoomId"))
root.append(etree.Element("Data"))
data_root = root[2]
data_root.append(etree.Element("Availability"))
data_root.append(etree.Element("Price"))
# Xml in code





def buildXmlUpdate(dfrom, roomId, ldays):   

    start_date_sard = dfrom
    roomId = str(roomId)  
    room_id_sard = roomId



    for n in ldays:
        print (dfrom, roomId, n)
        ldays[-1]['avail'] = str(ldays[-1]['avail'])
        ldays[-1]['price'] =str(ldays[-1]['price'])
        availability_in_data = ldays[-1]['avail']
        price_in_data = ldays[-1]['price']

    root[0].text = start_date_sard
    root[1].text = room_id_sard
    data_root[0].text = availability_in_data
    data_root[1].text = price_in_data
#here execute the function 

buildXmlUpdate('21/12/2015', 1, [{'avail': 1, 'price': 100}, {'avail': 3, 'price': 120}])
doc.write('testoutput.xml', pretty_print=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the case that you want your script to build an XML packet as you've shown, there are a few issues.

- You're doing a lot of swapping of variables around, simply to convert them to strings - for the most part you can just use the Python string conversion (`str()`) on demand.
- In your loop, the data you are trying to deal with is in the variable `n`, however, when you are pulling data out, it's from the variable `ldays`, which means the data you are trying to put into your XML is the same, regardless of the number of times you go through the loop.
- You've built an XML object with a single "Availability" element, and a single "Price" element, so there is no way, given the code you presented, you are ever going to generate multiple "Availability" and "Price" elements as in your sample XML file.

This isn't necessarily the best way to do things, but here is a potential solutions, utilizing the paradigms you've already established:

```
from lxml import etree

def buildXmlUpdate(dfrom, roomId, ldays):
    root = etree.Element("UpdateInventoryRequest")
    root.append(etree.Element("StartDate"))
    root[-1].text = dfrom
    root.append(etree.Element("RoomId"))
    root[-1].text = str(roomId)
    root.append(etree.Element("Data"))
    dataroot = root[-1]

    for item in ldays:
        dataroot.append(etree.Element("Availability"))
        dataroot[-1].text = str(item['avail'])
        dataroot.append(etree.Element("Price"))
        dataroot[-1].text = str(item['price'])

    return root

myroot = buildXmlUpdate('21/12/2015', 1, [{'avail': 1, 'price': 100}, {'avail': 3, 'price': 120}])
print etree.tostring(myroot, pretty_print=True)
```

Again, this is only one possible way to do this; there are certainly more approaches you could take.

And if you haven't already, I might suggest going through the [LXML Tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) and trying the different things they go through there, as it may help you find better ways to do what you want.

Comment: @MarcosR.Guevara If you like my answer, please accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: @MarcosR.Guevara You should see a check-mark beside the question, if you click it, then it should go green to show the accepted answer.  Thanks!